# spring boot primefaces fileupload doesn't work

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, spring-boot

I'm trying setup an application with spring boot and primefaces but the fileupload function doesn't work. I've tried several configurations without success. Please can someone help me with this problem.

This is the config:

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-02</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-02</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

Spring Boot `Application` class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
             SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(new Class[] { Application.class, Initializer.class});
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener()         {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(new ConfigureListener());
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<RequestContextListener> requestContextListener()         {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<RequestContextListener>(new RequestContextListener());
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean contextFilterRegistrationBean() {

    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    FileUploadFilter fileUploadFilter = new FileUploadFilter();
    registrationBean.setFilter(fileUploadFilter);
    registrationBean.addServletRegistrationBeans(servletRegistrationBean());
    registrationBean.setOrder(2);
return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.setPort(8083);
    return tomcat;
}
```

JSF Form

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload}" />
    </h:form>
```

JSF Backing Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FileBean {
private UploadedFile file;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    System.out.println("in handle file upload...");
    UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
    System.out.println(file.getFileName());
    //application code
}
```

Comment: What does *"Doesn't work"* mean? Any errors, exceptions or messages?

Comment: For starters stop mixing different spring boot versions also stop mentioning the explicit spring dependencies as those might interfere with Spring Boot ones. Leading to suprising issues. Next instead of configuring the `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` just for setting the port simply add the `server.port` property to the `application.properties` file. Your application class appears to be missing a `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.